# TypeScript: How to have object within a class and then use it in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

## The Issue

I'm creating a Class which will have a lot of variables. Most of them are logically grouped and I want to utilise the IDE (VS Code) benefits of auto suggesting.

The issue is that there are a lot of variables and I don't want to list all of them upfront, I want to have nesting so if I create `const movie1 = new Movie(1, 101);`, then when I start typing `movie1.` the IDE to start autosuggest all thins on the first level, like `id`, `title` ... etc.

And then when I go further with typing `movie1.title`, the IDE to give me hints that object have, like `bg`, `en`, and `original`.

**Actual result**

The VS Code gives me hints. But when I run the script I'm getting an runtime error

```
this.id.googlesheet.row = rowID;
        ^


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'googlesheet')
    at Movie (~/src/classes/Movie.ts:12:17)
    at <anonymous> (~/src/index.ts:5:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/src/index.ts:8:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Object.j (~/dist/cjs/index.cjs:1:1197)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:283:17)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:233:7)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)
```

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, I tried utilising interfaces but I ended in a dead-end.

## Files

**src/index.ts**

```
import { Movie } from "./classes/Movie";

const movieList: Movie[] = [];

const movie1 = new Movie(1, 101);
const movie2 = new Movie(2, 102);

console.log(movieList[0].id.googlesheet.row);
```

**src/classes/Movie.ts**

```
export class Movie {
    id: { googlesheet: { row: number; movie: number; }; wordpress?: { bg?: number; en?: number; }; };
    title: { bg: string; en: string; original?: string; };
    metadata: { duration: string; yearOfProduction: string; };
    country: { bg: string; en: string; };
    description: { bg: string; en: string; };
    director: { bg: string; en: string; };
    trailer: { url: string; };
    featuredImage: { url: string; };

    constructor(rowID: number, movieID: number) {
        this.id.googlesheet.row = rowID;
        this.id.googlesheet.movie = movieID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create the properties first: `this.id = {}; this.id.googlesheet = {}; // Or whatever`. They don't just magically come to life.

Comment: @InSync I'm creating them within the constructor. Maybe I'm not following you.

Comment: You are not, hence the error. You [should have been warned](https://tsplay.dev/wXydLN), even.

Comment: You should consider compiling with [the `--strict` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), or, at the very least (in this instance), [the `--strictPropertyInitialization` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization).  That would catch the error you have here where you have not, in fact, initialized your properties. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?